# What are the pros and cons of having a repeater control in a 3-tier application?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, 3-tier

In terms of data accessing, or any other opinions.

If possible, state a better alternative if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repeater control doesn't have any bearing on whether you have a good or bad 3-tier application. It's simply a pre-built ASP.NET control that you can use to iterate over data. That data can be anything from a datatable to strongly typed class from your model-tier.

We usually stray away from using repeaters unless we are doing something that requires event handling.

Server controls in general have a lot of overhead because they're meant to abstract the web (they also have their own life-cycle) and provide hooks for binding and event handling. If you don't need to do any event handling, then I would recommend just using a simple loop.

Comment: I disagree with using a loop in place of a repeater.  The advantage of server side controls is that they pre-process data in events and only render the content later.  If an error occurs it is usually in the pre-processing part and allows you to cleanly redirect to an error screen instead of dealing with half a generated page.  Also this type of overhead of server side controls is really not an issue--it's a tiny fraction of the total time spent processing the request.

Comment: I think it definitely depends on the type of data that you're processing. Ideally, your "business" or "data" layer should be doing all of the processing and presenting a clean list of data to the front-end. The front-end shouldn't be worried about data not being in the right state to present - in my opinion, that type of validation should have happened earlier in the app.

Comment: IMO programmers should be defensive and not assume the data they get is "clean".

Comment: Sorry, yes, obviously, I didn't mean that you should assume it's perfect, I was just pointing out that the "processing" should really be done ahead of time and not on the code-behind of an aspx page. Of course you should always have appropriate validation at all levels.